# IM trying to run a loop with in another loop, but my out put is always zero

Tags: python, for-loop

```
l=eval(input("How many CDs are bieng processed"))
m=0
s=0
l=0
for i in range(l):
    n=eval(input("How many Tracks are on the CD:"))
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        m=m+eval(input("Minutes in Track :"))
        print(m)
        s=s+eval(input("Seconds in Track :"))
        print(s)
sec=m*60+s
minute=sec//60
second=sec%60
print("Total time:",minute,"Minutes",second,"Seconds")
```

Add code to first ask how many CDs are to be processed (you may assume the value entered is non-negative). Use this number to determine how many times the program will go through one loop (known as an outer loop) that contains within it the code from part 1. Since the loop from the code of part 1 will now lie within the loop you are developing for this part of the assignment, it is known as the inner loop. At the end of each pass of the outer loop your program should identify the CD being processed as CD1, CD2, etc. and then report the total time of that CD. Thus we may see output such as:

Comment: Your both loops are using the same variable (i).

Comment: Oh, look, a shameless post for an assignment! Gasp! Seriously, though, you could have edited it to look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting l back to 0 after you accept your input. (on line 4)

Try this:

```
l=eval(raw_input("How many CDs are bieng processed"))
m=0
s=0
for i in range(l):
    n=eval(raw_input("How many Tracks are on the CD:"))
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        m=m+eval(raw_input("Minutes in Track :"))
        print(m)
        s=s+eval(raw_input("Seconds in Track :"))
        print(s)
sec=m*60+s
minute=sec//60
second=sec%60
print("Total time:",minute,"Minutes",second,"Seconds")
```

**EDIT:**

```
l=eval(raw_input("How many CDs are bieng processed"))
    m=0
    s=0
    for i in range(l):
        n=eval(raw_input("How many Tracks are on the CD:"))
        for i in range(n):
            print(i)
            m=m+eval(raw_input("Minutes in Track :"))
            print(m)
            s=s+eval(raw_input("Seconds in Track :"))
            print(s)
        print("Time for this CD: m: %s s: %s" % (m,s))
    sec=m*60+s
    minute=sec//60
    second=sec%60
    print("Total time:",minute,"Minutes",second,"Seconds")
```

Comment: Ok i fixed it, thank you. but how do I make it so after each iteration of l, it prints out the time for the specific CD being processed, labeled CD1 CD2 etc

Comment: edited the answer. If you find it useful, please mark it as answer

Comment: after the first cd is processed it continues to add on the values of the previous CD instead of starting over